# React native app gets crash logs with "SIGSEGV: Segmentation violation (invalid memory reference) "

Tags: android, react-native, segmentation-fault, bugsnag

I've just integrated the bugsnag in my react native app and suddenly I started receiving Segmentation violation (invalid memory reference) reports for the android phones only. The logs don't show where the error happens, I can see only this line -onlyreanimated::NativeProxy::installJSIBindings()

The app doesn't crash in development(on simulators) or during the testing, the breadcrumbs are not useful either.

Has anyone received similar logs and how did you pinpoint what the issue is? Any advice is greatly appreciated as I'm going in circles trying to figure this out.

Comment: We can check the Crash log in Android Studio logcat have you tried this way to figure out the reason for the crash?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to this [issue on code push](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/2284), I'm facing the same problem here, using RN 0.70.4. And the react-native-code-push library seems to have some other problems with the new versions, like [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/pull/2369).

Comment: any update on this issue, we are not using code-push, still getting the same error.